# Difference between $stdin and others gets.chomp

Tags: ruby

Hello everyone I am a novice to learn Ruby 
i am practicing to get the data from the file

```
puts "what is your filename?"
filename = $stdin.gets.chomp
```

from the line two I can get the filename I want to read
However, if I just write gets.chomp it will turn into an error
I have already known $stdin means standard input but still cannot understand this
can anyone help me? THX

Comment: oh!I find that gets.chomp can work ,too!! So, I cannot realize what $stdin works for now@@

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When invoking `gets` without specifying the stream, we are invoking [Kernel#gets](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-gets) and when stream is specified we are invoking [IO#gets](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/IO.html#method-i-gets)

I believe `Kernel#gets` wraps around `IO#gets` under the hood but before it needs to create an IO object, that IO object will be a concatenation of all command line arguments(ARGV) ( it will try to open every single one as file in positional order) and them read from it.  If  there are no elements left on  ARGV it will then read from stdin.

That behavior can be tested with this simple snippet:

```
while gets
        puts $_
end
```

When running `ruby myscript.rb` without parameters it will read stdin, if parameters are specified it will try to open as files and read from it, it will works similarly to `cat` command .

That stream could be tty, socket, file etc:

```
stream = File.open('/etc/passwd','r')

puts stream.gets 

stream.close
```

A simple http client using sockets:

```
require 'socket'

s = TCPSocket.new 'icanhazip.com',80

s.puts <<~EOF
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: icanhazip.com

EOF

while line = s.gets
        puts line
end

s.close
```

[More about Kernel#gets here](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-gets)

[More about IO#gets](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/IO.html#method-i-gets)

Comment: "if the stream is not specified it reads from `$stdin`" – If you are talking about [`Kernel#gets`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-gets), then no, it doesn't. If you pass any argument, it will first interpret anything in `ARGV` as a filename and read from that, and only after it has read all the files named in `ARGV`, will it read from standard input (similar to how [`ARGF`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0_preview2/ARGF.html) works). (And, BTW, I'm not even sure if it reads from `$stdin` then, or from `$<` instead.)

Comment: _"gets is a method which reads one line from a stream, if the stream is not specified it will ..."_ – you are describing two different methods as if they are one. The former is the instance method [`IO#gets`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/IO.html#method-i-gets), the latter is the global function [`Kernel#gets`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Kernel.html#method-i-gets).

Comment: @Stefan, I addressed that now thanks. Is is safe to say that `Kernel#gets` wraps around `IO#gets` ?

Comment: Yes, it uses `IO#gets` to read from files and from the standard input. But it doesn't switch to _stdin_ after reading from the list of files. It only reads from _stdin_ if the list of files (`ARGV`) is initially empty. If files are given, it reads from these files and stops after reading the last file.

Comment: @Stefan, if I redefine `IO#gets` it's not called when I invoke `Kernel#gets`: `class IO; def gets; puts "in IO#gets"; end; end`. When invoke  `gets` then enter `3` (return), `"3\n"` is returned. Am I missing something?

Comment: @CarySwoveland like other core methods, it doesn't bother to invoke the Ruby implementation but instead calls the underlying C method directly.

Comment: @Stefan, I see. Thanks.